# How does Fuse work?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If you have a card like Profit and Loss you get the Fuse special rule

[image]

I'm a little unclear how it works?

- Do you have to cast both sides in the same turn?
- If you don't can you cast one of the spells twice?
- Can you discard the card after only playing one of the spells?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No matter how you cast a Fuse spell, you're still casting the card as a single spell, and all the normal parts of casting a spell still happen. You pay mana, put it on the stack, it resolves, and it goes to your graveyard. You just get to choose as you cast it whether you're going to cast one of the sides or both. If you cast both sides, you're casting them together as a single spell all at once, not as two separate spells at two different times. Think of it as a spell that has three possibilities for its cost and effect(s): the left side, the right side, or both sides. But no matter what it's still one card, one spell. So:

- No, you don't have to cast both - the reminder text says "you may cast one or both".
- No, you can't cast one of them twice - the card doesn't say you can.
- The card goes to your graveyard after you're done, whether you cast both sides or just one. (You're not discarding it, though. You're putting it from your hand onto the stack, it resolves, and moves to your graveyard. "Discard" in Magic means specifically hand to graveyard.)

Perhaps you were confused by the fact that it says "...from your hand" in the reminder text, making you think that you could somehow cast just one part of it out of your hand, leaving the other part there. But the reason it says "from your hand" is to clarify that you *can't* do this special Fuse thing when the card's somewhere else, for example if it's in your graveyard and has been given Flashback by [Snapcaster Mage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Snapcaster%20Mage). (In that case, since Fuse doesn't apply, it acts like a normal split card - you can flash back either half, for its mana cost, ignoring the other half.)

For more descriptions of how Fuse works, see its section in the official [Mechanics of Dragon's Maze](http://www.wizards.com/magic/magazine/article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/feature/242#1) article.

Comment: What does happen to Profit and Loss if it's targeted by Snapcaster? What's the Flashback cost, and what can you cast with it?

Comment: @GendoIkari I thought going into detail about that was a bit out of scope of the question - I only mentioned it at all because I thought the "from your hand" was possibly what confused the OP - but I can add it if you like.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't belong as an answer to the question; I was just asking out of separate curiosity. But I looked it up myself, thanks.

Comment: @GendoIkari Ah, okay. I put it in as a parenthetical anyway, since I guess you're probably not the only one who'd get curious.

Answer (score 4):

When you cast a spell with fuse, you have three options:

1. Cast the left half for its cost
2. Cast the right half for its cost
3. Cast both halves for both costs

Choosing any one of these options causes the entire card to go on the stack and then (unless an effect says otherwise) to go to the graveyard after it resolves.  As with a normal spell, while the spell is on the stack, regardless of which option you chose, you can't cast any part of the spell again.

> Can you discard the card after only playing one of the spells?

"Discarding" refers only to moving a card from your hand directly to the graveyard without playing it, and you can only do that when a cost or effect demands or allows it.  If you're referring to the act of placing an instant or sorcery into a graveyard after it resolves, that is not discarding; that is simply the last step in resolving an instant or sorcery.  Regardless of how many parts of a fuse card you use, the entire card is still cast and *must* (not "can") be placed into the graveyard upon resolution.