# How do you counter a fuse card?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If your opponent plays a card with the fuse special rule and opts to play both sides you get a chance to respond.

If you're holding a counterspell do you dispel one or both spells of the fuse?

Comment: For what it's worth, I think my answer to http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/14371/how-does-fuse-work did answer this, though not directly: it says "you're casting the card as **a spell** ... **it** goes on the stack ..." (emphasis added) and so on - it's just one spell, so there's just one thing to target with a counterspell.

Comment: P.S. Just noticed, more directly, that answer also said "If you cast both sides, you're casting them together as a single spell all at once, not as two separate spells at two different times." I'll go edit a little more to clarify, since the title of that other question was "how does it work?" so I guess you might as well have a general answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is actual still one spell so "both spells" is not the correct term. So yes, both halves would be countered.

Here the full rules of Fuse:

> 702.101 a Fuse is a static ability found on some split cards (see rule 708, “Split Cards”) that applies while the card with fuse is in a player’s hand. If a player casts a split card with fuse from his or her hand, the player may choose to cast both halves of that split card. This choice is made before putting the split card with fuse onto the stack. The resulting spell is a fused split spell.
>
> 702.101b A fused split spell has two sets of characteristics and one converted mana cost. The converted mana cost of the spell is a number equal to the total amount of mana in its two mana costs, regardless of color.
>
> 702.101c The total cost of a fused split spell includes the mana cost of each half. (See rule 601.2e.)
>
> 702.101d As a fused split spell resolves, the controller of the spell follows the instructions of the left half and then follows the
>   instructions of the right half.

Answer (score 4):

The rules use imprecise wording as they instruct you two cast two things ("cast both halves"), but it is well known that only one spell (consisting of a fusion of both halves) is being cast, and it is implied by other rules ("*A* fused spell...").

Only one spell is cast. Only one spell is on the stack. Countering the spell counters the "both halves".